# how to panic kernel from user land

Tags: c, kernel

I need to panic kernel after some operations are done and verify what operation did

Can some one help me to know if there is any way? I searched a lot but no luck

I am looking for some generic call

thanks in Advance!

Comment: Just write a driver that'll access invalid memory when called. Or unplug the machine.

Comment: Assuming Linux: http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/02/debug-kernel-panics-with-crash/

Comment: if you just want to panic (and not debug) you can also use a simpler module (also assuming linux): http://www.dufault.info/blog/forcibly-triggering-a-kernel-panic-on-linux/

Comment: Why -1for the question ? It's an interesting question !

Comment: I currently on HP-UX, but want a generic solution across OSes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Higher address range is mapped to the kernel. This if you write something there e.g. Say 0xFFFFFF7 kernel exits your process with a segmentation fault complaining that illegal memory location was accessed. 
In user land your process is more like a sand box and any illegal access of memory outside your process is fined with kernel killing your process with a segmentation fault violation.

To panic a kernel you can try to set some wrong hardware registers typically with invocation of a syscntl sys call.

Comment: yes, that's true. but i don't want core dump of my process. I need to explore a bit on how to use syscntl for my purpose.

Comment: I have fixed bugs that were result of wrong arguments to syscntl for register manipulation :-)

Comment: I like it ;) Let me find out how to add this bug :) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can try a [sysrq trigger](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt):

```
echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

> 'c' - Will perform a system crash by a NULL pointer dereference.
>         A crashdump will be taken if configured.

Comment: but how if i'm not on linux?. I am thinking of common code across many OS HP/AIX/Linux/Sol/   etc. Might be a small driver will be okay. But i tried to explore if something common available already :(

Comment: @cnicutar and the sysctl sys.kernel.sysrq must be set to 1